# BASH: Getting history editing like Kornshell

Tags: bash

Let's say I execute the following command in either BASH or Kornshell:

```
$ foo | while read line
> do
>    echo "Line = '$line'"
> done
```

If I have `vi` set, and edit it in Kornshell, I get:

```
foo | while read line
do
     echo "Line = '$line'"
done
```

If I have `vi` set, and edit it in BASH, I get:

```
foo | while read line;do;    echo "Line = '$line'";done
```

Is there a way I can get command line editing in BASH the same way Kornshell works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the `lithist` (literal history) option which tells bash to retain the newlines:

```
$ shopt -s lithist
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be one of the `shopt` settings, but had no idea which one.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

```
$ shopt -s cmdhist  # This is on by default, so probably unnecessary
$ shopt -s lithist  # This is off by default
```